# regular expression with javascript for second match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an complicated string. From this string I like to get only the following marked part: (second match)

**Example**:

> 1;#FirstName,,
>   Surname,#Domain\Account,#email.@company.com,#email@company.com,#FirstName,,
>   Surname25;#**FirstName,,
>   Surname**,#Domain\Account,#email.@company.com,#email@company.com,#FirstName,, Surname26;#Helpdesk,#DE\helpdesk,#helpdesk@vega.com,#,#Helpdesk30;#...

I only want to get the Second "FirstName,,Surname" combination...
Any ideas how I could to this?

In the example above I need to ignore the complete first part starting from 1;# to 25;#
And then I need the "FirstName,,Surname" and after that the rest of the string should be ignored.

The numbers can be different and also the length from the string...

I started with this but it is not working:

```
((.*?[0-9]+.*?){2})[0-9]+
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check my answer. You will have in the 1st group of the match what you need. **What programming language are you using?**

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what "FirstName" and "Surname" could be?

Answer (score 0):

you can use string split function and split by var arry = yourstring.split(',') arry[9],arry[11] will contain your string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is not possible for me. Because sometimes the string before can be shorter or longer... Sorry forgot to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
(?:.+?;){2}#(.+?),#
```

*(very weird string by the way)*

You can see it working here: http://regex101.com/r/dV1lW5 and here: http://regexr.com?33rn5
[image]

Comment: I tried to use this but it seems not to be working. (nintex regex action)

I also tested it here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and with some other regex-tester and its also not working here...

Comment: @Simon You just have to access to the 1st group of the match.